# Update returning undefined

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, update

I'm trying to learn to code in Apex and LWC for fun, but I'm having an issue here that I've been able to understand why:

**Apex class**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static void sellItem (String itemBarcode) {
    Inventory__c item = [SELECT Id, Item_Name__c, Status__c, Item_Barcode__c
                        FROM Inventory__c
                        WHERE Item_Barcode__c =: itemBarcode];
    try {    
        if(item.Status__c == 'Available') {
            item.Status__c = 'Sold';
        }
        update item;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**LWC**

```
@api itemBarcode;
@api itemToSell;

handleChange(event) {
    this.itemBarcode = event.target.value;
}

@wire(sellItem, {itemBarcode: '$itemBarcode'})
wiredSellItem({error, data}){
    if(data) {
        this.itemToSell = data;
        console.log(data);
    } else if(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}

handleCheckOut() {
    sellItem({ itemBarcode: this.itemBarcode })
        .then(() => {
            return refreshApex(this.itemToSell);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Unable to update the record => ' + error.message);
        });          
}
```

**HTML**

```
<lightning-card 
    title="Checkout a Book" 
    icon-name="standard:article"
>
    <div class="slds-m-around_small">
        <lightning-input 
            label="Item Barcode Number"  
            onchange={handleChange}
        >
        </lightning-input>
        <div class="slds-m-top_x-small">
            <lightning-button 
                label="Checkout" 
                variant="brand" 
                title="Checkout a book" 
                onclick={handleCheckOut}
            >
            </lightning-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

When I type the item's barcode in the lightning-input I click on the button to 'sell' the item with that barcode. The problem here is that it's not updating the item's status and the console.log in the LWC component is returning the error message with 'Unable to update the record => undefined'
However, when I try the Apex code on the developer console, it updates. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Inventory__c getItem(String itemBarcode){
    return [SELECT Id, Item_Name__c, Status__c, Item_Barcode__c
            FROM Inventory__c
            WHERE Item_Barcode__c =: itemBarcode];
}

@AuraEnabled
public static void sellItem(Inventory__c item){
    if(item.Status__c == 'Available'){
        item.Status__c = 'Sold';
    }
    try {
        update item;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@wire(getItem, {itemBarcode: '$itemBarcode'}) item;

handleCheckOut() {
    sellItem({ item: this.item })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('SUCCESS', result);
            return refreshApex(this.item);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Unable to update the record => ' + error.message);
        });          
}
```

Comment: Your `error.message` is undefined, which is why you're getting that console.log.  Use this resource for more information on how to debug your LWCs: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/debug_intro

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to use DML in `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)`, and you're not allowed to use `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)` in `@wire` methods. You need to call the `sellItem` imperatively.

You need to change:

```
@wire(sellItem, {itemBarcode: '$itemBarcode'})
```

To:

```
@wire(getItem, {itemBarcode: '$itemBarcode'})
```

With appropriate Apex code to get the item:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
public static Inventory__c getItem (String itemBarcode) {
    return [SELECT Id, Item_Name__c, Status__c, Item_Barcode__c
                        FROM Inventory__c
                        WHERE Item_Barcode__c =: itemBarcode];
}
```

And you need to set the imperative call to not be cacheable.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
public static void sellItem (String itemBarcode) {
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. The method 'sellItem' will continue the same? Just changing the cacheable to false?

Comment: @JoaoFelipeBarbosa Nothing else is needed, that's it.

Comment: So will I remove it? How the Status__c will be updated?

Comment: @JoaoFelipeBarbosa You need sellItem, so you would not remove it. But you cannot use it as a wire method, because it performs DML. You need a separate method (e.g. getItem) in order to retrieve the data for a record as well.

Comment: could you check my edit? Because it's still returning undefined. I'm not understanding how it's working

Comment: @JoaoFelipeBarbosa `sellItem` needs to specifically be `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)`, as `@AuraEnabled` is the same as `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)`.